# How to swap images url in styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to swap two background-image urls in the styled component , but my code it's not working , I don't know it‘s my syntax problem or something else. I checked the styled component website, but I didn't find anything similar.

```
background-image: ${props => 
    props.failed ? "url(${ progressFailed })":"url(${ progress })"
};
```

Comment: I assume `progressFailed` and `progress` are variables you have defined somewhere in your code. If so, you need to use backticks, `\``, for string interpolation. See [MDN's article on template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to interpolate the `progressFailed` and the `progress` variables as well. Right now they're just being treated as string and not being evaluated.

```
export default styled.section`
  background-image: ${props => 
    props.failed ? `url(${progressFailed})` : `url(${progress})`
  };
`
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you so much , you are amazing. it's working now.

Comment: @YouYi glad it helped :)